# how to have regular expression for a textfield which accepts all characters except a comma (,) and do not accept a white space at both ends

Tags: regex

How to write a regular expression  for  a text field which accepts all characters except a comma (,) and do not accept a white space at both the ends? I have tried

```
[^,][\B ]
```

but no use

like 'product generic no'  instead of 'product,generic,no' or '  product  generic  no  '

Comment: Is a blank input (ie no characters) acceptable? It passes your criteria as stated. Also, what language are you using?

Comment: @Bohemian no empty text is inacceptable and i am using extjs/javascript

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expression for such a simple test?

Comment: @core1024 because most of the times  data is entered by some layman and later it is used for naming a product..and how can i achieve that without regex if i want to restrict them

Comment: I should have been more specific. Is a single character acceptable? The reason I ask is that saying "yes" increases the complexity of the problem

Comment: @Bohemian no we may have atleast 3 chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a solution without regular expression. As you said you're using JS so the function is in JavaScript:

```
function isItInvalid(str) {
    var last = str.length - 1;
    return (last < 2 || 
            str[0] == ' ' ||
            str[last] == ' ' ||
            str.indexOf(',') != -1);
}
```

**EDIT:** Just made it a bit more readable. It also checks if the string is at least 3 chars.

Comment: by using this we can display error msg after entering data ..but i want to restrict while entering

Comment: Just instead of `regex` use the `validator` option ;) See how here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186595/extjs-dependent-field-validation

Comment: this worked but i am unable to restrict to not to enter :(                  validator: function(value){
       var last = value.length - 1;
          if((value[0] == ' ' ||value[last] == ' ' )){
           return 'Space not Allowed at start and end';
          }
          if(value.indexOf(',') != -1) {
        return ', not allowed';
     }else {
              return true;
           }
        }

Comment: You can use `maskRe` to restrict the comma like that `maskRe: /[^,]/,`. This works per character (i think) so don't try to filter the space.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Perl regular expression

```
/^\S[^,]*\S$/
```

This should work from 2 characters up, but fails in the edge case where the string has only one non-comma character. To cover that too:

```
/^((\S[^,]*\S)|([^\s,]))$/
```

Comment: I fixed it, it seems.

Comment: @SxG  no, i tried again, it doesnt allow space in middle

Answer (score 0):

Something like below:

```
/^\S[^,]*\S$/
```